# Universal App Links and multiple debug SHA256 fingerprints

Tags: android, sha256, android-keystore, applinks

We are in the process on integrating [Universal App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations). The setup requires a file named `assetlinks.json` to be uploaded to a web service, so that associations can be verified.

When generating a fingerprint for a debug build, the default `debug.keystore` is used. This means that each developer will have a different SHA256 fingerprint.

Obviously, having each developer generate the fingerprint specified to his or her machine and then adding it to the `sha256_cert_fingerprints` array in the `assetlinks.json` file is not palpable.

Is there a modification that can be made to the `assetlinks.json` file or a process we can use so that testing Universal App Links while debugging will work on any developers machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can share the debug.keystore between developers or create a new one that is only used for testing/debugging universal apps and is shared.